# How to set a program so the program keep pressing a specific key?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard

I have a program that needs to have F1 key is to be pressed. Of course I can put a heavy object on the F1 key to make it be pressed all the time. But, this way, that means I limited to a single program. I need to work on another program application but I only have one laptop.

So, are there a program to solve my problem?
program that do something like this:

- Open a list of current proccess
- Assign a specific key to a specific proccess
- able to minimize the proccess. So, while minimized, the program make the proccess keep  press F1

Any command prompt or other tricks is welcome too. I am using Windows 10

Comment: There are ways to "put a rock on the key" that don't involve actual rocks. But the key strokes will always go to the active window. If  you want to work on a different program, you won't be able to send key strokes to this one.

Comment: Look into with Google, etc. AutoIT... it should be possible...

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible, but likely not simply.

F1, specifically, is a global command to open Help. Because of this it is likely going to be difficult to extricate it from the OS where it has meaning and lock it to a specific process.

One method may be to run a virtual machine and then virtually press the virtual F1 only inside that virtual machine using AutoHotkey or something similar. This way, so far as the virtual OS and application know, F1 is being pressed and focus is being held by the application, while you're still working and interacting with other programs on the host without interrupting it.